# Are questions that will go out of date "on topic" for this site?

Tags: discussion, good-questions, scope, close-reasons

Are questions that will go out of date "on topic" for this site?

For example, the answers to the question [Is it safe to travel to Japan due to the nuclear situation?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73/is-it-safe-to-travel-in-japan-due-to-the-nuclear-situation) could conceivably become incorrect as time goes on.

Should we accept such questions on this site?

Comment: This is similar to a question I just asked before I saw this one: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-might-we-cope-with-answers-that-change-over-time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, because you don't know for how long it won't be relevant. Also, the question is only time-relevant for people planning to travel there, but who knows what value questions like those have for future users (perhaps for someone doing a report, or if a similar event happened).

I would say if it has broad enough value currently, even if only for a year, it's a decent question.

Answer (score 12):

StackExchange websites do not need to only hold perpetually true information.

For instance, [Webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) questions become irrelevant extremely fast, as most websites change their features/rules very often.

Comment: This. There is a difference between "Information that will change sometime in the future" and "Information that is only relevant right this instant and will never be useful again". The former is fine. The latter is probably dicey.

Comment: Question about Fukushima situation, IMHO, falls into the first group (it may change in future, we don't know when). Other questions may fall into "too localized" category and be closed.

Answer (score 9):

I would say, for most of the questions asked on this site, they WILL be time relevant. Visa information changes on a yearly basis. Revolutions/uprising/crime changes constantly. I think this site needs to accept time based questions.

Answer (score 5):

Don't be so pessimistic. There could be another nuclear incident and then some of the information (eg about lettuce) would be relevant again!

Answer (score 2):

The questions, that are accurate now, and may change in the future, but we don't know when exactly, should be fine here.

Questions that are specific only to a certain point in time, (like concerning value of exchange rate, current, non-recurring events), should be closed as "too localized".